# Armor to vs Armor of

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

> you are the armor to your soldiers

> you are the armor of your soldiers

Is their a difference in meaning between the two?

Comment: Sentences like these need more context to get truly useful answers, because they are very vague.  The responses below have to speculate what you are trying to say and in what setting you are talking.  Did you read this somewhere?  Are you trying to write a poem?  Are there other statements that are parallel to these?  All this would be helpful to know to give you a correct answer.

Comment: I read it in a poem; there are several praises for the leader but not metaphorical ones.

Comment: Then it is a metaphorical expression indicating the relationship to the soldiers or more probably how the soldiers view the relationship from their point of view.  In other words, "you portray the image of armor to the soldiers."

Comment: Perhaps we are overusing the word "metaphorical."  The following are perfectly normal phrases: "You are a great mother to your kids" or "You are a wonder to your kids."   The sentence "You are armor to your soldiers" could be using the same structure.

Comment: Poetry cannot be analyzed as normal English because poets are not constrained by the rules of grammar or the standard meanings of words. A poet could reword this any way they chose and it would still be "correct" because it's poetry

Answer (score 1):

"Armor to" doesn't make sense in this context. "To" indicates a destination or recipient. Like, "I walked TO the store" or "Sally gave the money TO Bob".

"Of" indicates possession or association. "Al is the father OF Bob" or "That is the job OF the shipping clerk."

You can't normally "be" "to" something. To use "to" there must be some action or motion. You are moving TO the destination. (Possibly literally, possibly not.)

That said, people occasionally use "to" to indicate a relationship. Like, "We go together well. You are the saucer to my cup. You are the wheels to my bicycle." But this is a relatively rare usage and I'd avoid it outside of expressions intended to be poetic.

Comment: So, I guess, in poetic contexts it is allowed, like saucer to my cup.

Comment: @Ammu Both suggestions are a little odd because they are clearly using a metaphor—you're addressing a person, and a person is not literally armor. It's confusing, though, because soldiers are exactly the people that sometimes use literal armor. Unless there's more context, the hearer might try to guess a completely unintended meaning ("Does it mean 'you *give* armor to the soldiers?")

Comment: @AndyBonner Yes. Just taking the sentence out of context, I'd think the writer means something like, "You do a good job of protecting the soldiers under your command." But that's just guessing. Yes, obviously (?), "you give armor to the soldiers" would be a literal statement.

Comment: yes, it is metaphorical. The person is glorified as a leader who is protecting his soldiers like an armor

Comment: Structures like "saucer to my cup" are not just poetical.  They are shorthand for a phrase something like "You have the same relationship to me that a saucer has to a cup."  It is a comparison between two pairs.  That is what licenses this unusual use of "to."  Being armor to someone does not invoke another pair of relationships, so is not as good an expression.  If you want to be metaphorical, you could just say: "You are armor for your soldiers" or "You are your soldiers' armor" or "You are the armor of your soldiers,"